# MySQL UPDATE with multiple tables and derived calculation

Tags: mysql, join, updates, calculated-columns

I'm in need of assistance with a MySQL UPDATE involving two tables and a calculated value. The biggest issue seems to be getting the derived value in place.

I need to calculate the DENS column based on the number of IDs in Table 2 (Total ID by FIPS / Table.POP)

Table 1

```
---------------------
| FIPS | POP | DENS |
---------------------
| 0001 | 100 |      |
| 0002 |  25 |      |
| 0003 | 500 |      |
---------------------
```

Table 2

```
-------------
| ID | FIPS |
-------------
| 01 | 0001 |
| 02 | 0001 |
| 03 | 0002 |
| 04 | 0003 |
| 05 | 0003 |
| 06 | 0003 |
-------------
```

I can't figure out the syntax for the UPDATE statement to properly associate the count and subsequent calculation with the FIPS value.

I thought the following might work but it has not:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.DENS = (
   SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT Table2.id) / Table1.POP )
   FROM Table2
   WHERE Table2.FIPS = Table1.FIPS
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Desired result would look like:

```
----------------------
| FIPS | POP | DENS  |
----------------------
| 0001 | 100 | 0.020 |
| 0002 |  25 | 0.040 |
| 0003 | 500 | 0.006 |
----------------------
```

The DENS is calulated from Table 2 and Table 1 (using POP: total IDs/POP = DENS) in that there are 2 IDs for FIPS 0001 (2/100 = 0.0200), 1 ID For FIPS 0002 (1/25 = 0.0400), and 3 IDs for FIPS 0003 (3/500 = 0.0060)

Comment: Are you sure that you want to *store* derived data.

Comment: the DENS value is necessary for a later (easier) calculation so I do need to store that value

Comment: For clarity, what would the desired result set look like?

Comment: Desired result now added in, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer ended up being  combination of both with the addition of the reset of innodb_lock_wait_timeout (set to 600)

```
SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 600
```

Final update code was:

```
UPDATE Table1 x
JOIN (SELECT t1.FIPS, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.ID)/t1.POP n
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.FIPS = t1.FIPS
GROUP BY t1.FIPS) y
ON y.fips = x.fips
SET x.DENS = n
```

Thanks to both Kordirko and Strawberry for the assist on this!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT FIPS, count( distinct ID ) As DENS
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY FIPS
) t2
ON t1.FIPS = t2.FIPS
SET t1.DENS = t2.DENS
;
```

Comment: Tried to run the update, got a Lock wait timeout exceeded error on two occassions. Table 1 has about 3000 records, table 2 has 1.5 million

Comment: Then increase `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` from default 50 seconds to much more, see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout  this query places shared locks on records in table2, if other sessions modify that table in the same time, they block each other.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the privileges to change that value and the admin is not available today. I'm getting the same error with Strawberry's solution so I'm suspecting I may not be able to do this without making that change

Comment: You don't need the admin - this is a session variable, you can change it for your session only using `SET SESSION var_name = new-value`. However, you **must be aware**, that other sessions will still be using 50 seconds, and they will get this error while waiting for your query to finish. Then, users can kill you :)

Comment: Ok, I've got a meeting I've got to run to but I'll give that a shot when I get back and let you know how it goes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(fips INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,pop INT NOT NULL
,dens DECIMAL(5,3) NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,100,NULL),
(2,25,NULL),
(3,500,NULL);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,fips INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,3),
(5,3),
(6,3);


UPDATE table1 x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT t1.fips,COUNT(t2.fips)/SUM(DISTINCT t1.pop) n FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.fips = t1.fips GROUP BY t1.fips ) y
    ON y.fips = x.fips
   SET x.dens = n;

SELECT * FROM table1;
+------+-----+-------+
| fips | pop | dens  |
+------+-----+-------+
|    1 | 100 | 0.020 |
|    2 |  25 | 0.040 |
|    3 | 500 | 0.006 |
+------+-----+-------+
```

...or something like that